# Method of Moments estimator (MME) with restriction on the parameter.

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation

> Given a sample $X_1,\dots, X_n$, where each random variable has a Bernoulli distribution $$P(X_i=1)=\theta, \qquad \text{ with }0<\theta<\frac12$$ what is the Method of Moments Estimator (MME) of $\theta$?

I know the MME without the constraints is $\overline{X}_n$. But is it still the same one with such constraints?

Comment: @JimmyR.So, if $\overline{X}_n$ is greater than 1/2, MME still adopts it? I find it odd in some sense, but thank you for your comment!

Comment: A ok, I see now the problem! No, you are right! Thanks

Comment: MME remains same as in the unconstrained case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method of moments works in the following way:

We have some kind of parameter $\theta$ that we want to estimate and we can represent this parameter as a function of (finitely many) moments of our distribution, i.e. $\theta = f(E[X], \ldots, E[X^k])$.

Now we try to estimate $\theta$ by estimating the moments and then plugging the estimated moments into $f$. Then we hope that under the right conditions we get a good estimate of our parameter.

Now the function $f$ is not uniquely determined. In your example you might want to choose $f(x) = x$, which will give you your standard estimator. But you might as well choose $f(x) = \min\{x, \tfrac{1}{2}\}$, this is pretty much up to you. Typically you should just choose a function that is continuous on some reasonably large set, so that your estimate is "asymptotically good".

Comment: Your $f(x)=\min\{x,1/2\}$ leads to the maximum likelihood estimator (definitely better than MME), but it is not the MME. There is no choice for the method of moments estimator; it is just the usual one.